# Get the name of the user running a process in C#

Tags: c#, process

I'm running C# code to kill all processes by a certain name (MSACCESS.EXE) but the problem I encounter is when a different user has logged into the computer and left the process running. In this case, when I try to access the process to get more info about it, I get a permission denied error. All I'd like to be able to do is to get the username(s) from the other processes and pop up a message to the user to the effect of "User XXX is logged into this pc, and has a lock on the database. Cannot proceed."

How can I get the name of the user, other than the current user, who has the process open?

Comment: @Quantic my mistake, sorry

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre all good, just dont want the question closed incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had googled that enough, but I guess I didn't ask the question correctly. Much appreciated.